# How to add a space after certain characters using regex Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string consisting of 18 digits Eg. 'abcdefghijklmnopqr'. I need to add a blank space after 5th character and then after 9th character and after 15th character  making it look like 'abcde fghi jklmno pqr'. Can I achieve this using regular expression?

As regular expressions are not my cup of tea hence need help from regex gurus out here. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why use regex for this in the first place? Just split the string into several substrings based on the length and then join them with a space character.

Comment: I don't know much Java so there's probably a more concise way but doing this in a very basic way would look something like `s.substring(0, 5) + " " + s.substring(5, 9) + " " + s.substring(9, 15) + " " + s.substring(15);`.

Comment: Post whatever you have done so far and then ask about wherever you are stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

Regex finds a match in a string and can't preform a replacement. You could however use regex to find a certain matching substring and replace that, but you would still need a separate method for replacement (making it a two step algorithm).

Since you're not looking for a pattern in your string, but rather just the n-th char, regex wouldn't be of much use, it would make it unnecessary complex.

Here are some ideas on how you could implement a solution:

1. **Use an array of characters to avoid creating redundant strings**: create a character array and copy characters from the string before
   the given position, put the character at the position, copy the rest
   of the characters from the String,... continue until you reach the end
   of the string. After that construct the final string from that
   array.
2. **Use Substring() method**: concatenate substring of the string before
   the position, new character, substring of the string after the
   position and before the next position,... and so on, until reaching the end of the original string.
3. **Use a StringBuilder and its insert() method**.

Note that:

- **First idea** listed might not be a suitable solution for very large strings. It needs an auxiliary array, using additional space.
- **Second idea** creates redundant strings. Strings are immutable and final in Java, and are stored in a pool. Creating
  temporary strings should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use regex groups to achieve that. Something like that:

```java
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z]{5})([a-z]{4})([a-z]{6})([a-z]{3})");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abcdefghijklmnopqr");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String first = matcher.group(0);
    String second = matcher.group(1);
    String third = matcher.group(2);
    String fourth = matcher.group(3);
    return first + " " + second + " " + third + " " + fourth;
} else {
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

*Note that pattern should be a constant, I used a local variable here to make it easier to read.*

Compared to substrings, which would also work to achieve the desired result, regex also allow you to validate the format of your input data. In the provided example you check that it's a 18 characters long string composed of only lowercase letters.

If you had a more interesting examples, with for example a mix of letters and digits, you could check that each group contains the correct type of data with the regex.

You can also do a simpler version where you just replace with:

```java
"abcdefghijklmnopqr".replaceAll("([a-z]{5})([a-z]{4})([a-z]{6})([a-z]{3})", "$1 $2 $3 $4")
```

But you don't have the benefit of checking because if the string doesn't match the format it will just not replaced and this is less efficient than substrings.

Here is an example solution using substrings which would be more efficient if you don't care about checking:

```java
final Set<Integer> breaks = Set.of(5, 9, 15);
final String str = "abcdefghijklmnopqr";
final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (breaks.contains(i)) {
        stringBuilder.append(' ');
    }
    stringBuilder.append(str.charAt(i));
}
return stringBuilder.toString();
```